# "AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'ravel'"

Tags: python, list, numpy

I have a system of differential equations and need to calculate the Jacobian. The code below throws `AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'ravel'`. What am I missing?

```
import numpy as np
import numdifftools as ndt

def rhs(z, t=0):
    x,y = z

    xdot = (x/5 + y)*(-x**2+1)
    ydot = -x*(-y**2+1)

    return [xdot, ydot]

Jfun = ndt.Jacobian(rhs)

Jfun([1,1])
```

Comment: Aside: if you're using Python 2, remember to either use `from __future__ import division`, pass floats, or write `x/5.0`.  Otherwise you'll get into problems with integer division (your fixed code returns the zero jacobian matrix otherwise.)

Comment: since this systems is going to be a user input and i therefore cannot guarantee the floating input, i guess `from __future__ import division` is the right thing to do?

Comment: Sure.  Or you can just call `float` on the user input, whether directly or by creating an `array` of float dtype.  Either will work.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Just do:

```
return np.array([xdot, ydot])
```

instead. This should work...

Comment: strange..i was pretty sure i've tried that before..anyway, it worked! thank you very much - i wish every problem could be solved in one line!

Comment: @klim I found out this was the problem based on your error message... since `ravel` is a method of the `ndarray` object, it was likely that returning the array instead of the list would solve the problem