# Python Plotting Combine 2 Plots

Tags: python, matplotlib, plot, attributeerror

I am trying to plot streamlines in matplotlib over a contour plot by combining these two plots shown below but showing my code first:

```
ax = plt.axes(projection=ccrs.PlateCarree())
ax.coastlines(lw=1)
clevs = np.linspace(-3., 3., 13)
cnplot = plt.contourf(lon,lat,anomspeed,clevs,add_labels=True,cmap='jet')
cbar = plt.colorbar(cnplot)
cbar.set_label('Standard Deviations')
plt.title('~50m Wind Speed Anomaly {} 2020'.format(calendar.month_name[currm-1]))
diffu = (uwndc - uwnd);  diffv = (vwndc - vwnd)
lonn, latt = np.meshgrid(lon, lat)
plt.streamplot(lonn[0,:], latt[:,0], diffu, diffv, density=(3.5,3.5), 
color='k',linewidth=0.4,arrowsize=0.6)#x,y 1D and u,v are 2D
```

[image]

I am getting this error (full traceback shown) when i try and run the code shown below but I do not understand 'ravel' error. I suppose it has something to do with matching coordinates or related between the two plots..? thank you for any help!

```
Traceback (most recent call last):

File "C:\Users\U321103\.spyder- 
py3\MonthlyReport_mapsNCEP_contour_monthly_wspdv2.py", line 85, in <module>
plt.streamplot(lonn[0,:], latt[:,0], diffu, diffv, density=(3.5,3.5), 
color='k',linewidth=0.4,arrowsize=0.6)

File "C:\Users\U321103\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\envs\Maps\lib\site- 
packages\matplotlib\pyplot.py", line 2906, in streamplot
if data is not None else {}))

File "C:\Users\U321103\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\envs\Maps\lib\site- 
packages\cartopy\mpl\geoaxes.py", line 1897, in streamplot
target_extent=target_extent)

File "C:\Users\U321103\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\envs\Maps\lib\site- 
packages\cartopy\vector_transform.py", line 146, in vector_scalar_to_grid
return _interpolate_to_grid(nx, ny, x, y, u, v, *scalars, **kwargs)

File "C:\Users\U321103\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\envs\Maps\lib\site- 
packages\cartopy\vector_transform.py", line 67, in _interpolate_to_grid
s_grid_tuple += (griddata(points, s.ravel(), (x_grid, y_grid),

AttributeError: 'Variable' object has no attribute 'ravel'
```

[image]

Comment: `ravel` is probably a reference to numpy.ravel, which is probably being called indirectly by something that you call.  You probably need to look at (or post) more of the traceback to figure it out.

Comment: hi tom10- i've included the full traceback - i'm learning python and I've scanned the traceback and it's not telling me very much:/ thanks,

Comment: Maybe `lon` and `lat` are just single numbers, but they need to be vectors to mesh them into a proper grid?

Comment: @user2100039: It looks like one of the variables you're passing into `streamplot` is not what `streamplot` is expecting; it's expecting the thing to have an attribute called `ravel` but it doesn't. Try `lonn[0,:].shape` for the first four entries, or `type(lonn[0,:])`, etc, to figure out what they are. I don't know what 'Variable' is, but it's not a normal python type, afaik; maybe they're from TensorFlow?

Comment: hi - what doesn't make sense to me yet, is that I can plot the streamplot above with just the plt.streamplot line above but not when i run the code trying to plot both images together.

Comment: @user2100039: It would be helpful if you'd post a short and complete example ([mcve](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)) that we could run to reproduce the behavior. Short of that, I'm going with the statistics I've learned after hundreds of SO answers: 95% of the time, "weird/unexpected behavior" is usually the result of a typo or small mistake somewhere in the code that's not posted, and not actually unexpected behavior in the underlying libraries.

Answer (score 0):

I'm looking to solving this same problem and I found an answer to a similar question that help me plotting streamlines and contour togheter. Take a look at [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22328847/attributeerror-list-object-has-no-attribute-ravel).

In a nutshell, instead of:

```
plt.streamplot(lonn[0,:], latt[:,0], diffu, diffv, density=(3.5,3.5), color='k',linewidth=0.4,arrowsize=0.6)
```

You'd use

```
plt.streamplot(lonn[0,:], latt[:,0], np.array(diffu), np.array(diffv), density=(3.5,3.5), color='k',linewidth=0.4,arrowsize=0.6)
```

The use of np.array() solves the problem for me.

Best regards,

Mateus